# Microsoft Fake Assemblies

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2017, microsoft-fakes

I'm trying to generate a ShimDirectory (from System.IO.Directory). In the test project references I right click on System and select Add Fakes Assembly. This creates mscorlib.fakes and System.fakes in the Fakes folder.

However, the namespace System.IO.Fakes contains only six class  (all Stub...) and no ShimDirectory, or any other shims I would expect.

Any ideas?

(Using VS2017)

Answer (score 0):

Okay - turns out the trick is to restart Visual Studio, delete the fakes and regenerate them and it works!